# Two Exhaust Vent on the ame circuit

Tags: exhaust-fan

Can I install two bathroom exhaust vents (adjacent bathrooms) on the same circuit but with each having their own switch?

Comment: How many watts or amps does each fan pull, or how many HP are the fan motors, for that matter?

Comment: From reading the code references that the experts have quoted on this site I would say there is no code requirement that would prevent wiring lights/fans in two different bathrooms on the same circuit. The only question would be to determine that the circuit can support the current draw of the two fans and any other loads.